# Recursive function in Python - Why line 7 was executed while if condition is false?

Tags: python, if-statement, recursion

I'm a newbie and this is my first stupid question on StackOverflow. Would anybody let me know why line 7 was executed while the condition is false (`input = 1`)? [This is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwo6J.jpg)
Thanks a lot and all the best to you!

```
print("line 1 - START OF CODE - right before function 'def decimalToBinary(num)' \n", "line 2-9 - define function 'decimalToBinary(num)'")
def decimalToBinary(num):
    print("\n Line 2 - execute the function 'decimalToBinay(num)'' \n Line 3 - right before if statement - at this line num value is:", num, ", var number is:",number,"\n")
    if num > 1:
        print("Line 4-5 - 'if statement' is true (num > 1), num value is", num, "> 1", "\n Line 6 - recall function 'decimalToBinary(num // 2)' \n")
        decimalToBinary(num // 2)
        print("Line 7 - 'if statement' end - This is num after line 6 'decimalToBinary(num // 2)'. Num is",num)
    print("Line 8 - This is num before the line 'print(num % 2)':", num)
    print("Line 9 - This is result of num % 2:", num % 2, "\n")
number = int(input("line 10 - Ask user 'Enter any decimal number:' then assign this value to var 'number' \n line 11 - call function 'decimalToBinary(number)': "))
decimalToBinary(number) #function call
print("line 12 - END OF CODE")
```

Comment: because there is no `return`.

Comment: I'm a little confused, the condition is the num being greater than 1, if input >=2 than that code block should run?

Comment: Can you please explain what output do you expect?

Comment: @Sven Eberth: thanks for your help. But I'm a little confused because line 7 belongs to the 'if statement' (line 4), so I think line 7 shouldn't execute while the condition is wrong,

Comment: @Sven Eberth: I expect line 7 should never be executed while `input = 1`

Comment: This wasn't your initial question... But right, it won't.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question, your assumption is if the input is 2, then `if num > 1`, will run of course. And then it goes to `decimalToBinary(num//2)`.
However, to do that you need to change line 6 to `return decimalToBinary(num//2)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to RETURN something from your function.  Then, as the recursion returns, you need to add this (least significant) digit to what you got from the parent.

```
def decimalToBinary(num):
    s = ''
    if num > 1:
        s = decimalToBinary(num // 2)
    return s + str(num%2)
number = int(input("Enter any decimal number:"))
print(decimalToBinary(number))
```